# PHP mysql_query parameter order

Tags: php

I'm a bit of a noob but I am having trouble finding the answer to this question. I have two pieces of code and both work but I'm not sure why.

```
// Connect to the database 
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
// Retrieve the score data from MySQL
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);            
mysqli_close($dbc); // close db
```

In the instance above the connection is the first mysql_query parameter and then the sql query. This came from a book and isn't how the PHP manual defines it as far as I can see.

In the next example the sql is entered first, then the connection and I have to specifically use mysql_select_db. Why do they both work?

```
//db connection
$dbc = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("database",$dbc); // select the db
$sql = "SELECT * from table"; // sql query 
$result = mysql_query($sql, $dbc); // make query on db
mysql_close($dbc);  //close the connection after data is acquired
```

Thanks in advance for any illumination you can supply.

Comment: What is DB_NAME in mysql_connect()? There's not database parameter in mysql_connect() function. That's why you have to use mysql_select_db() in that case.

Comment: DB_NAME etc are global connection variables I defined in a require_once file. I did think about changing them before posting. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
```

Is a function call to the newer mysqli library, [http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Your second example

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $dbc); // make query on db
```

Is a function call to the mysql library, [http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)
Both calls match the signature and order of arguments to those functions.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to supply the links and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query); // MySQLi (link, query)

$result = mysql_query($sql, $dbc); // MySQL (query, link)
```

Comment: Oh wow. I couldn't see that for looking as they were on different pages. I feel illuminated but also a little dim :)

Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You're using [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) in the first example, and [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) in the second.

Two different function with two different parameter order, that's why I "love" PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would have scratched my head for hours!

Comment: (sidenote) Not just different parameter order, their parameters are different. Also mysqli_* functions depend of mysqli class (alias functions)... but mysql_* don't ;)

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 I'm aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

Because mysql_query() expects query as first parameter and mysqli_query() expects your query as 2nd.

mysqli_query

```
mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode ] )
```

mysql_query

```
mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier ] )
```

`mysql_select_db()` is required because `mysql_connect()` **doesn't have database as parameter**, instead of `mysqli_connect()`.

Answer (score -1):

The function `mysql_select_db` let you choose another db along your code without the need of 'another' new connection, using the same connection you started with `mysql_connect`.

Comment: that's not an answer to this question.